# RegEx to extract strings delimited by tokens

Tags: javascript, regex

From the string:

```
"@user do foo, and bar please, #urgent. contact xyz"
```

I need to extract this array of 3 strings:

```
["@user", "do foo, and bar please, #urgent", "contact xyz"]
```

What I currently do: I simply `indexOf()` the tokens `"@"`, `" "`, `". "` and get the sub-strings in between.

I would like to optimize it with a RegEx. How can I look for several tokens and group them together like in the array?

Comment: `indexOf()` might actually be a less expensive operation than regex here. However, it's not too difficult with regex either. You probably don't even need to focus on certain characters as tokens. https://regex101.com/r/tKuM77/6

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
string input = "@user do foo, and bar please, #urgent. contact xyz";
string pattern = @"(@[\w]+)";   // inclusive split, @User will be included in the split result
string[] regexSplit = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

foreach (string str in regexSplit)
{
    // exclusive split, . won't be included in split result
    string[] res = str.Split(new char[] { '.' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    output.AddRange(res);
}
```

Please note:
\w means any alphanumeric char
(@[\w]+): means @ sign followed by one or more alphanumeric char, we put them in Parenthesis, so it would become an inclusive split.